# Skype Bot Rest API Conversation ID

Tags: botframework, skype, skypedeveloper, direct-line-botframework

So I used an account and message my skype bot.

I get this json response on my endpoint url. I sent a text "add"

```
{"text":"add"
,"type":"message"
,"timestamp":"2017-01-13T15:38:32.242Z"
,"id":"1234567"
,"channelId":"skype"
,"serviceUrl":"https:\/\/smba.trafficmanager.net\/apis\/"
,"from":{"id":"29:yyyy","name":"Real Person"}
,"conversation":{"id":"29:yyyy"}
,"recipient":{"id":"28:xxxx","name":"Skype Test"}
}
```

When I return a reponse to this url using yyyy as conversationId

> POST /v3/directline/conversations/{conversationId}/activities
>   https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/yyyy/activities

with this parameter:

```
{
  "type": "message",
 "text": "registration",
  "from": {
    "id":"xxxx","name":"Skype Test"
  },
  "recipient": {"id":"yyyy","name":"Real Person"}
}
```

I get an unknown conversation response. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: How exactly did you get your conversation Id? Did you use POST to https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations in order to get one?

Answer (score -1):

Your Response should look like:

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "recipient_id",
        "name": "recipient_name"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "conversation_id",
        "name": "conversation_name(if available)"
   },
   "recipient": {
        "id": "from_id",
        "name": "from_name"
    },
    "text": "response_text",
    "replyToId": "activity_id"
}
```

Hope that Help :)